# gsutil - no locks available

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Has anyone seen this error from gsutil or know how to fix it?  I get it when I try to run any gsutil command, but here is an example trying to use ls on a bucket in my google cloud project.

```
$ gsutil ls gs://BUCKET/FOLDER
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 68, in <module>
bootstrapping.PrerunChecks(can_be_gce=True)
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 279, in PrerunChecks
CheckCredOrExit(can_be_gce=can_be_gce)
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 167, in CheckCredOrExit
cred = c_store.Load()
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 206, in Load
cred = store.get()
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 350, in get
self.acquire_lock()
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/multistore_file.py", line 222, in acquire_lock
self._multistore._lock()
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/multistore_file.py", line 281, in _lock
self._file.open_and_lock()
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/locked_file.py", line 370, in open_and_lock
self._opener.open_and_lock(timeout, delay)
  File "/home/gmcinnes/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/locked_file.py", line 211, in open_and_lock
raise e
IOError: [Errno 37] No locks available
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  The filesystem on that machine was full.  I cleaned it up and it works now.

```
$ df 
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1 10079084 9678804 0 100% /
```